# Multi threading multi client chat server

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, chat, outputstream

The title was bad i know but let me explain my situation. Okay, i am making a server that sits off to the side and communicates with my minecraft client. I can get one client to connect and transfer data back and fourth. When I try to connect with a second client i get the error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at ConnectionHandler.setupStreams(ConnectionHandler.java:71)
at ConnectionHandler.HandleChat(ConnectionHandler.java:30)
at ConnectionHandler.<init>(ConnectionHandler.java:23)
at Server.waitForConnection(Server.java:118)
at Server.RunAll(Server.java:65)
at Server.run(Server.java:50)
at ServerTest.main(ServerTest.java:9)
```

Now in consequence, here is the resulting code:

setupStreams: Line 71

```
public static void setupStreams() throws IOException
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= Server.ConnectionArray.size(); i++)
    {
        Socket TempSocket = (Socket) Server.ConnectionArray.get(i - 1);
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(TempSocket.getOutputStream());//Line 71
        output.flush();
        input = new ObjectInputStream(TempSocket.getInputStream());
        whileChatting();
    }
}
```

Now i feel it would be best to explain how all this code is set up:

It starts in a Class called ServerTest.Java
Code:

```
public class ServerTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Server Minecraft = new Server();
        Minecraft.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Minecraft.run();
    }
}
```

I called the object "Minecraft".

Now the class that it refers too implements the Runnable class and begins with the run() method. Here is that method:

```
@Override
public void run()
{  
    RunAll();
}

public void RunAll()
{
    ConnectionHandler.showMessage("Waiting for client connections...");
    try
    {

        server = new ServerSocket(1337, 10);
        while(true)
        {
            try 
            {
                waitForConnection();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException Exception)
    {
        Exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
       ConnectionHandler.closeCrap();
    }
}
```

Now from here it waits for connections and i think it loops back repeatedly but i don't know. Here is the code for that Method:

```
public void waitForConnection() throws IOException
{
   connection = server.accept();
   ConnectionArray.add(connection);
   ConnectionHandler connections = new ConnectionHandler(connection);
   connection = null; 
}
```

Now i think that what this method does is accepts the incoming connection from the client then adds that connection to my array of sockets, then hands the socket off to the handler class then sets the original socket back to Null to to wait for another incoming connection.

Now this bring us to the ConnectionHandler class.
In here it takes a socket X and sets it to the global socket as shown here:

```
static Socket Socket;
public PrintWriter Out;
String Message = "";
public static ObjectOutputStream output;
public static ObjectInputStream input;
public static int Players = 0;

public ConnectionHandler(Socket X)
{
    this.Socket = X;
    HandleChat();
}
```

This class also implements the Runnable class. But as you can see it is setting the global socket to X then running HandleChat(); Here is the Method:

```
public static void HandleChat()
{
    try
    {
        setupStreams();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

As you can see all this is doing is running the setupStreams(); method. Here is that method aswell:

```
public static void setupStreams() throws IOException
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= Server.ConnectionArray.size(); i++)
    {
        Socket TempSocket = (Socket) Server.ConnectionArray.get(i - 1);
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(TempSocket.getOutputStream());
        output.flush();
        input = new ObjectInputStream(TempSocket.getInputStream());
        whileChatting();
    }
}
```

Now i "Think" This method creates a new socket called TempSocket and making it = the latest connection in the array then setting the output and input streams to that socket resulting in a socket for that individual client then runs whileChatting(); Here is the resulting code:

```
public static void whileChatting() throws IOException
{
    String message = "";
    do
     {
         try
         {
             message = (String) input.readObject();
             showMessage("\n" + message);
             sendMessage("", message); 
         }
         catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException)
         {
             ConnectionHandler.showMessage("\n idk wtf that user sent!");
         }
      }while(!message.equals("/stop"));
}
```

Again with the "Thinking" here. I think the read object is being set to the String message; Then being sent to the client and displayed on the consoles screen. (Swing) following this is the code for both methods (Send) and (Show):

```
public static void sendMessage(String message, String returnedMessage)
{
    try
    {
    if(!message.isEmpty())
    {
        output.writeObject("\247c[Server]\247d " + message);
    }
    else
    {
        output.writeObject(returnedMessage);
    }
        output.flush();
        showMessage("\n[Server] " + message);
    }
    catch(IOException ioException)
    {
        Server.chatWindow.append("\n ERROR: DUDE I CANT SEND THAT MESSAGE");
    }
 }

static void showMessage(final String text)
   {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater
      (
         new Runnable()
         {
            public void run()
            {
                Server.chatWindow.append(text);
            }
         }
      );
   }
```

Now as you can see here, When i would like to display a message on the client's side; I want it to look like: [Server] text. Also you will notice that it also sys returned message. I have the client set up to only sent to the server then display whats returned on screen so lets say i type "Hay" It will display nothing on my screen upon sending but then once the server receives it it will send me exact text back to everyone. That's the sendMessage(); Method. Now the display method is rather simple. it displays text upon receiving.

That's the code in a nutshell basically. I would rather leave you with too much information i can than leave you sitting here wondering what is going on. Once more i am going to explain my situation more in depth. I am making a server that communicates with my minecraft client. one client connects fine but when another client tries to connect it errors and when the first client disconnects, the server will not allow the client to re-connect. I think that may have something to do with the array of connections and the socket is not being removed from the array upon disconnect but i dont know. Now finally, my question for you is how can i fix these errors? Thanks in advance for any replies i get on this question.

Comment: Array list for connections:

     public static ArrayList<Socket> ConnectionArray = new ArrayList<Socket>();

Comment: So what you are saying is that i should call setupStrems from the main method in the server class run()???

Answer (score 0):

It seems on every user connection you call setupStreams which loop through all connections.

That means if User 1 connect you open the output socket for the user
the second user connect you again loop through all connection and again open output steam for user 1 which already opean.
you need to setupStreams you can't open the output stearm for user twice\
also I think you have error here

```
   for(int i = 1; i <= Server.ConnectionArray.size(); i++)
```

you start from 1 not from 0. and compare with <= not <.
I don't know why, and what is the type of ConnectionArray.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void waitForConnection() throws IOException
{
   connection = server.accept();
   ConnectionArray.add(connection);
   ConnectionHandler connections = new ConnectionHandler(connection);
   connection = null; 
}
```

`connection` is not found, so either this is not the actual code, or you are storing this temporary variable in a member or global. In either case, increasing the scope of temporary variables to span different functions is bad, with multiple threads its like juggling chainsaws. BTW: It would be more natural to store the connection handlers in a list than creating them and storing their sockets in a list. This is a case where the responsibilities are unclear, leading to unclear and buggy code.

While the above case could be harmless still, it still shows bad and dangerous style. You keep on with this style (at least it's consistent!) with "...it takes a socket X and sets it to the global socket as shown...":

```
static Socket Socket;

public ConnectionHandler(Socket X)
{
    this.Socket = X;
}
```

Making `Socket Socket` static, it is shared between all instances of this class, which is obviously not what you want. You should now know why globals are considered bad and why class-statics are only globals in disguise.

Summary: Decide who accesses which parts. If it's just one object, make the parts private members, so the compiler makes sure it's really only one object. Try not to share state. If multiple objects and threads access an object, plan how they don't get in each others way.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using some kind of API, because this is just (*sorry*) messy code.[This](http://netty.io/)
is the one I use. It does everything for you, it creates the Thread, opens the socket and it is event based! So you dont have to loop through all your sockets reading all the data, you get notified when something is avaiable!

Comment: It would be nice if you would also show some example by code.

Comment: [link](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-5.x.html) There you go. Those are the examples from their website